# Curve with increasing curvature is a circle

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, curves, curvature

Let $\gamma$ be a curve in $\Bbb R^2$ such that it has (not necessarily strictly) increasing curvature $K$. Can this curve be a $C^2$ closed curve ? The answer I was given was no if $\gamma$ is not a circle. This was the proof :

If $\gamma : [0, a] \to \Bbb R^2$ is a $C^2$ closed curve, then $K(0) = K(a)$. So the curvature cannot be increasing except the case where it is constant which means that it is a circle.

I disagree with the "$K(0) = K(a)$" part : the curve $t \mapsto (t^2(t-1), t(t-1))$, $t \in [0,1]$ is $C^2$ and closed but calculations show that $K(0)\neq K(1)$. Putting away this counterexample, the curvature of a curve depends on its speed and acceleration and there is no reason for both of them to be equal at a same position for different time.

I agree with the initial statement however but it needs another proof in my opinion.

Comment: I think the issue might be that the curve is not actually $C^2$ as a map $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$. 

We have $\gamma'(t) = (3t^2-2t,2t-1)$ so that $\gamma'(0) = (0,-1)$ and $\gamma'(1) = (1,0)$. Thus, $\gamma'(0) \neq \gamma'(1)$ and the velocity is not continuous at that point. You can see this if you graph the function, as there is a sharp "edge" at the origin where a particle following this curve would have to either slow to a stop or make an instantaneous $90^\circ$ turn.

Comment: @Flumpo $\gamma_x$ and $\gamma_y$ are polynomials so they should behave very well, why would this map not be $C^2$. To me continuity is a punctual property, what happens at $t=0$ has nothing to do with $t=1$ if we consider $t$ as representing time for example

Comment: @Flumpo you were right :D

Comment: Actually think I made a mistake to be fair, since the property comes from the closed part rather than it being $C^2$

Comment: Think I was thinking of it as a map from the circle rather than $[0,1]$, which might work as an alternate definition if you're still in the market for one.

Answer (score 1):

By closed curve, the question meant that speed and acceleration where equal at the intersection point, so $K(0)=K(1)$